# How do I display a router parameter in an input box in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, url, routes, ngmodel

I currently have my routes set as follows in my Angular project:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'defect', component: AppComponent },
  { path: 'defect/:start', component: DefectComponent }
];
```

Then in the TS of my DefectComponent I have:

```
//route is declared in my parameters as ActivatedRoute
ngOnInit(): void {
    let temp = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('start');
    if(temp) {
      this.timestamp.TestStart = temp;
    }
  }
```

In the html of my DefectComponent I have:

```
<input id="TestStart" [(ngModel)]="timestamp.TestStart" placeholder="Time">
  <button class="findSteps" (click)="createCases(timestamp)">
    Find Failed Cases
  </button>
```

I figured this would autofill my input with the 'start' parameter when I call it with a url like:

```
http://localhost:4200/defect/272020-02-06_0348100661PM
```

because it was added to timestamp.TestStart onInit, but right now it still is just displaying "Time." Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thoughts I've already had:

- Does ngModel come before the ngOnInit?
- Am I somehow passing the parameter into the url wrong?

UPDATE: temp is currently being set to null instead of the input. Any thoughts on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event: any) => {
      let r = this.route;
      while(r.firstChild) {
        r = r.firstChild;
      }
      r.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.timestamp.TestStart = params.start;
      })
    })
  }
```

This worked!

Answer (score 1):

start is a queryParameter (occurs in the URL after a ? character).

So you should use queryParamMap instead of paramMap.

OR the url should be more like

http://localhost:4200/defect/272020-02-06_0348100661PM

Either way, it will come in as a string, and you'll have to parse it into a Date object if you need it.

Comment: I tried just changing paramMap to queryParamMap and it didn't seem to work (temp was still null). I also tried changing the url as you mentioned and it was also still null. Am I doing something else wrong? :/

Comment: The way you've set up your route is as a regular parameter, not a query parameter.  { path: 'defect/:start', component: DefectComponent } this will produce a route like http://localhost:4200/defect/272020-02-06_XXX.  So I would use paramMap.

Comment: Also, are you injecting in route?  You don't show your constructor so we have no way of knowing.  It's of ActivatedRoute type.

Comment: Finally, I would use the params observable instead of snapshot:  this.route.params.subscribe(params => console.log(params));

Comment: My ngInit looks like his now: `this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params) => {       let temp = params.get('Start');       console.log(temp);     }`

Comment: and my constructor is as follows: `constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { } so I believe it should be injecting it`

Comment: but it still is coming out as null even when I do the url as you specified

Comment: If you can post a codepen it will help us help you diagnose the issue.

Comment: I got it working with the answer I just posted. I'm going to accept that one once it lets me, but I gave you the upvote for all of your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your route currently is expecting a 'route parameter'. Something like

```
http://localhost:4200/defect/<some-value>?<query-params>
```

would be what your url should look like. I believe that is what is causing your issues.
If you update your route and remove `/:start` or do something like `defect/start` for the route and then add the query params you should get the desired behavior.

Comment: I updated the route in the question to what I've been trying and I've still been getting null. Any ideas?